# How would one mock an axios.all request?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, axios, moxios

I've came across this wall while i was mocking my project.

I make an axios.all request with 10 requests within it. How the hell do i mock it?

I'm currently using moxios to mock my axios http requests but it doesn't seem to have the functionality to deal with this problem.

Example:

```
axios.all([
    axios.get(url1),
    axios.get(url2),
    axios.get(url3)
    ])
    .then(axios.spread(function (r1, r2, r3) { 
    ...
    }))
.catch(err => {
    console.error(err, err.stack);
});
```

Has anyone come accross this problem and have they found a solution?

Update:

I've just mocked each request invidually but it's a slow and painful process, is there a quicker more efficient way to do this?

Comment: I'm currently struggling with the same problem. Have you found any solutions yet?

Comment: @mazedlx I ended up just mocking each request using moxios and using the stubrequest method to mock each one. Not the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

The way I got around this was using `async` and `await` to ensure that the function waits until it's finished running before making assertions.

I wasn't using moxios, but instead [axios-mock-adapter](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter/) but I have a feeling the issue can be resolved in the same way.

Given the above problem, I solved it like this...

In my component I have a method like so

```
getTheThing () {
  axios
  .all([
    axios.get(`/api/endpoint/1`),
    axios.get(`/api/endpoint/2`)
  ])
  .then(
    axios.spread((response1, response2) => {
      this.setState({
        firstThing: response1.data,
        secondThing: response2.data
      })
    })
  )
}
```

and in my tests...

```
mock = new MockAdapter(axios)
mock
  .onGet(url1)
  .reply(200, mockData1)
  .onGet(url2)
  .reply(200, mockData2)



it('should set issue state after fetching the requested issue', async () => {
    await component.instance().getTheThing()
    expect(whateverItIsYoureExpecting)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up mocking it.`axios.all` in this case has 2 calls. mockAxios will loop twice. I used the `axios-mock-adapter` package.

The Axios call (This applies to `Promise.all` as well)

```
      axios.all[
         await axios.get('endpoint1'),
         await axios.get('endpoint1'),
       ]
```

The mock

```
       const mockData1 = [1, 2, 3];
       const mockData2 = [3, 2, 1];

       MockAxios.onAny().reply(config => {
            // Use your config to return different responses.
            // This mock will loop through every request in the Promise.all
            if(config.url === 'endpoint1') {
                return [200, {data: mockData1}, config];
            } else if(config.url === 'endpoint2') {
                return [200, {data: mockData2}, config];
            }
        });
```